# how can i send email from my application using registered Android email without password

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I want to send some text from my application to custom email address

i need to use email which is registered on device

i try many examples which is using **email and password** ,or using **Intent** , but it's ***not correct*** for me

So how can i do this, which will looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvp6y.png)

Comment: did you try Gmail Api ??

Comment: can you see the picture i've attached? 

will **Gmail Api** give me whole functionality?

Comment: yes You Can do It With Gmail API.. Read Gmail APi Tutorial In Android Development Forum.

Comment: and what permissions i need to add?

Comment: You HAve To Create OAuth In Developer Console .. And Get Account And Internet Permission

Comment: @JJG: Please note that not everybody uses Gmail.

Comment: What you want is not possible in general, as otherwise this would be a source of spam.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ohk For Good Information :) I was Just Told Which I Used To Doing This

Answer (score 0):

Use below code that will ask the user to open and Email Client for sending the email -

```
String to = "sarkerpt@gmail.com";
        String subject = "Barcode Reader For Android - Bug Report";

        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```